# Is there a Perl module that can split one master Pod file into several views?

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-pod

I want to write one Pod file for `perlop` and `perlopref`.  My gut instinct is to say something like

```
=head1 PRECEDENCE

blah

=head1 OPERATORS

=head2 "X"

=for short

The double quote circumflex operator surrounds an interpolating string.
See L<perlop/"X">.

=for long

-head3 Description

blah blah blah

-head3 Example

blah blah blah

-head3 See Also    

blah blah blah

=head2 qq(X)

=for short

The generalized double quote circumflex operator surrounds an interpolating
string. See L<perlop/qq(X)>

=for long

-head3 Description

blah blah blah

-head3 Example

blah blah blah

-head3 See Also    

blah blah blah
```

And have it produce (perlopref)

```
=head1 PRECEDENCE

blah

=head1 OPERATORS

=head2 "X"

The double quote circumflex operator surrounds an interpolating string.
See L<perlop/"X">.

=head2 qq(X)

The double quote circumflex operator surrounds an interpolating string.
See L<perlop/"X">.
```

and (perlop)

```
=head1 PRECEDENCE

blah

=head1 OPERATORS

=head2 "X"

=head3 Description

blah blah blah

=head3 Example

blah blah blah

=head3 See Also    

blah blah blah

=head2 qq(X)

=head3 Description

blah blah blah

=head3 Example

blah blah blah

=head3 See Also    

blah blah blah
```

Comment: My spidey senses tell me we're going to have an increase of pod questions on here for the next little while. :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, but I do have a suggestion for a couple places you could start. The first is [Pod::Inherit](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Pod::Inherit), which is a tool that DBIx::Class uses to produce POD that includes the documentation of inherited methods from superclasses. The second is [Pod::Weaver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Pod::Weaver) which is a general-purpose POD munger used by Dist::Zilla that has its own flavor of rules-based configuration, and could probably do what you need without a lot of work -- but it's a little light on documentation right now.